# "Building dependency tree" on apt-get takes too long

Tags: apt, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Ever since I installed Ubuntu "Building dependency tree" has always taken more than 10 minutes to finish, this happens for installing/removing/upgrading/updating. It does eventually finish though. I've tried to empty `/var/cache/apt`, but it has had no effect. If it matters I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2

Comment: for me it's been 2 hours and it's now 62% :D